# Problema ao inserir dados no banco de dados mysql pelo java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Meu código java está funcionando, mas ao adicionar dados a uma tabela SQL, os campos estão sendo preenchidos como NULL, mesmo tendo adicionado valores.

Parte do código em que ocorre a inserçao:

```
public void salvarCliente() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Connection conexao = new FabricaDeConexao().retornaConexao();


    String query = "INSERT INTO cli(nome,endereco,cpf) values (?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement stmt = conexao.prepareStatement(query);

    stmt.setString(1, textFieldNome.getText());
    stmt.setString(2, textFieldEndereco.getText());
    stmt.setString(3, textFieldCpf.getText());


    stmt.executeUpdate();
    stmt.close();
    conexao.close();

}
```

OBS: O código estava funcionando corretamente. O erro começou quando adicionei um método de remoção de dados. Utilizei o comando:

```
String query = "delete from cli where id=(select max(id))";
```

Para apagar o ultimo registro inserido na tabela(remoção feita pela ID).

Em vez de apagar o ultimo registro, ele apagou todos os dados da tabela e a partir de então começou a inserir os valores como NULL.

Comment: Esse comportamento é tanto quanto estranho, tem certeza que os `textField`s estão populados, e não estão nulos? E poderia nos disponibilizar o formato da tabela?

Comment: Sim, insiro todos os dados corretamente, conforme criado no banco, menos a ID, pois coloquei para incrementar automaticamente. Segue a tabela criada.                                                                                   create table cli(
id int not null auto_increment,
nome varchar(50),
endereco varchar(50),
cpf varchar(43),
primary key(id)
);

Comment: Amigo, me desculpe a demora da resposta, não passei um bom fim de semana.
A sua query, ela realmente funciona sem informar o `FROM` no subselect? Talvez seja isso que esteja acontecendo de errado.

Comment: Valeu pelo retorno, consegui resolver o problema com o auxilio do meu professor da faculdade, o erro era o seguinte, nessa minha classe provider, que tem a implementação dos metodos, coloquei para estender a minha classe cadastroCliente( extends cadastroCliente), onde tem a parte visual, e quando dava  'stmt.setString' com os textfield, ele sempre pegava os valores da outra classe, que são nulos. Para resolver, no metodo da classe cadastroCliente passei os textField por parametro, e fui passando ate chegar na classe provider, ai só dei set nas minhas variaveis.

Comment: Se for preciso posso disponibilizar o codigo aqui para quem tiver duvidas parecidas.

Comment: Responda a sua pergunta com a solução e vote nela como melhor resposta, assim encerra a pergunta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valeu pelo retorno, consegui resolver o problema com o auxilio do meu professor da faculdade, o erro era o seguinte, nessa minha classe provider, que tem a implementação dos metodos, coloquei para estender a minha classe cadastroCliente( extends cadastroCliente), onde tem a parte visual, e quando dava 'stmt.setString' com os textfield, ele sempre pegava os valores da outra classe, que são nulos. Para resolver, no metodo da classe cadastroCliente passei os textField por parametro, e fui passando ate chegar na classe provider, ai só dei set nas minhas variaveis